# How to use scheduler.at in rufus?

Tags: rubygems, rufus-scheduler

I can use `scheduler.cron` & `scheduler.in` in [rufus](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler) but `scheduler.at`.

I tried below based on the sample (`scheduler.at 'Thu Mar 26 07:31:43 +0900 2009'`) from the author.

- scheduler.at 'Nov 08 09:45 +1000 2011' (+1000 because I am in Sydney)
- scheduler.at 'Tue Nov 08 09:50 +1000 2011'
- scheduler.at 'Nov 08 09:45  2011'

But nothing worked. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I did some research over the internet and I have found a running/good example. Hope it helps...
http://codex.heroku.com/past/2010/4/15/rufus_scheduler_for_my_tiny_sinatra_apps/

Comment: That example comes from the original manual `scheduler.at 'Thu Mar 26 07:31:43 +0900 2009' do` and it doesn't work for me....